# Firebase is not sending SMS message to my app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-authentication

the problem is that it does work sometimes, then after testing too much the code doesn't execute
and the program stock not receiving any SMS 
even I'm not getting any errors 
, I don't have a number for testing in my sign-in method
, in my code, I mostly did it programmatically as my humble knowledge my code is fine and I delete the user from firebase but it doesn't work also

[image]

```
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!){ 

    PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(codeTextField.text!+phoneTextField.text!, uiDelegate: nil) { (ID, err) in
                    if let eror = err {

                        print(eror.localizedDescription)
                        AlertController.showAlert(self, titel: "خطا", message: "تاكد من اتصالك بالانترنت")
                       self.sendButton.loadingIndicator(false)
                        self.sendButton.setTitle("إرسال الرمز", for: UIControl.State.normal)

                        return

             }

                    guard let verifyId = ID else {return}
                    self.userDefaults.set(self.phoneTextField.text, forKey: "phone")
                    self.userDefaults.set(self.codeTextField.text, forKey: "ccode")
                    self.userDefaults.set(verifyId, forKey: "verifivationID")
                    self.userDefaults.synchronize()

                    let nextVC = OTP()
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)


                    // Sign in using the verificationID and the code sent to the user
                    // ...
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you're getting throttled, since you're sending to the same phone number too frequently. You'll want to [whitelist any phone number that you use for testing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth#test-with-whitelisted-phone-numbers), to prevent that from happening.

Comment: thanks, frank still the same error, the app still froze